# How can I find where the 404 error is caused in Spring-framework project using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm working on a Spring-framework project of my own. When I just ran the project, the result keeps showing 404 error, without any other error message. How can I find where the error occurred?

I have tried printing a message at the start of the Controller, and it wasn't printed. So I guess that the error occurs before the Controller.

This is a part of applicationContext.xml file:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mappers/**/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.my.test" />
    </bean>

    <mybatis:scan base-package="reserving" />
```

This is a part of dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:view-resolvers>
        <mvc:jsp prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    </mvc:view-resolvers>
    <context:component-scan base-package="reserving" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

This is a part of web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<!--        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I expect the result page shows a json Query that the Controller returns, but only 404 error occurs, before even going inside the Controller.

Comment: Are you doing this to learn? If so, the entire configuration style you're learning is obsolete, in large part because this configuration is prone to exactly these kinds of errors. Spring Boot is the modern way to do things, and none of this configuration _at all_ is required, just the controller.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'll try working on Spring Boot!

Comment: where is your controller code.

Comment: It doesn't even go inside the controller, so I think there is nothing to do with controller. That's why I passed appending the controller code.